# Access command line options/flags passed to nodejs executable

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-interface, flags

There is a wide range of [command line options](https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html) which can be passed to the node executable, as in

`node --inspect-brk --no-warnings test.js`

How do I access these options inside my test.js script?

Answer (score 1):

Flags passed to the `node` executable will be available inside the script as [`process.execArgv`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execargv). In the given case, this will contain:

```
[ '--inspect-brk', '--no-warnings' ]
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use, process.argv

eg: test.js file has the following code

`console.log("command line arguments");
console.log(process.argv);`

when you execute the file : node test.js 10 20 30
output: 
[ 'node path',
  'file path',
  '10',
  '20',
  '30' ]

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is not correct. `process.argv` contains arguments given to the script, not arguments given to node itself. Please make sure to read questions carefully. Also, please format code in your answers accordingly using backticks (`) to make them more readable.

Comment: @panepeter, sorry for the confusion. formatted the code.